# metadata in Orfeo Toolbox Orthorectification

Tags: metadata, orfeo-toolbox, orthorectification

I'm using Orfeo Toolbox to orthorectify a WorldView-3 Basic Imagery Product. The process seems very straight forward. I just input the image and a DEM of the area, and Orfeo gives me an orthorectified image, so apparently everything is very fine. However, I'm wondering whether the process is actually correct... how can I be sure that the software is actually using the information contained in the associated files (attitude file, metadata file, etc)?

Comment: Sorry, I dont find the option to include the DEM and RPC files in Orfeo (Geometry tool). Pease, review the attachment. ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsXXX.jpg)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/132047)

Answer (score 2):

OTB do include test for support of WV3 geometry. I supposed that the format is pretty much the same as WV2 which explain why the process run without errors. Nevertheless there is still a bit of work to check that the orthorectification is correct

Even if it's not a quantitative validation (sensor modelling validation can be tricky question) you should try to superpose the output image with Open Street Map or any georeferenced data over the same area to check the geometry.

Don't hesitate to give feedback about your experimentation on otb-users mailing list (google groups). The remaining work for a complete support of WV3 is probably not much in OTB in my opinion and starting the discussion on the mailing-list is a good starting point to gather ideas.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks. When superposing a road network from Open Street Map, there is some displacement (few meters), but it is within the expected error and it seems that there is no other important geometric distortions. I mean, this displacement is approximately the same throughout the image and can be easily corrected with a small (x,y)-offset transformation.

I´ll give this feedback in the otb-users mailing list, thanks a lot.